# How to manage navigation in Android TV alternatively how to use native React to handle remote navigation?

Tags: android, react-native, react-hooks

When we create a screen, the screen will function flawlessly on an Android TV emulator, but when we create a build for testing on a real Android TV, we will run into a number of additional problems. For example, the remote will not function, and no buttons or letters will be clickable, and the navigation will not function.

I need solutions ..please help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.